# Get element id name on html element

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can we get dom element id name ? i understand that we can get element id by using
document.getElementById('test'); as shown in the example below .

Html code

```
<html> 
 ..
 ..
 <table id = 'test'>
 <tr id='test'> </tr>
 </table>
</html>
```

Example : knowing id is 'test' , instead of specifying get document.getelementbyid(..), i am trying to
get id name without document.getelementbyid method

example usecase

```
const getid = d3.select('table')
//this will return the html tag, this point i am trying to retrieve the id name. 
//i have tried
getid.id , getid.getDocumentById() .
```

Is this even possible with JS?

Comment: you could use querySelector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try
`d3.select('table').attr("id")`

https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/blob/v2.0.0/README.md#selection_attr